# Text showing in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, jquery-selectors

I am trying to run a simple sequence with text. I want the text to show for a second and then `hide()` or `fadeOut()`, then the `next()` one within the queue to show.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Right now, only the last div is showing.

Side note, can anyone point me to a function or give me an idea of how to make the text slide in from the right, like on this page. https://artversion.com/

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cover1-seq').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).show().prev().hide();
    next();
  })
  /*.toggle("slide", {
     direction: 'right'
    }, 1000);*/
});
```

```css
.cover1-seq {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover1-seq">
  <h1 class="cover1-title">Apple</h1>
</div>
<div class="cover1-seq">
  <h1 class="cover1-title">Book</h1>
</div>
<div class="cover1-seq">
  <h1 class="cover1-title">Cat</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript is executing all at once, in the case 3 times the '$(this).delay(1000)', what will happen is that it will execute everything together.

I made an adjustment in your code to run every 1 second:

```
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $(".cover1-seq").each(function(){
    $(this).delay(1000 * ++i).queue(function() {
      $(this).show().prev().hide();
    });
  });
});
```

Or, as asked, so it keeps repeating. And to execute when the page loads, we add the '$(document).ready':

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var arr = $(".cover1-seq");
  var arrLen = arr.length;
  var i = 0;

  setInterval(function(){
    $(".cover1-seq").hide();
    $(arr[i]).show();
    i === arrLen ? i = 0 : i++;
  }, 1000);

});
```

I hope I have helped!

Comment: Thanks! How do I get it to run in an infinitive loop? Also, anyway to get the first one to show immediately on page load?

Comment: I updated the code to always repeat and execute when loading the page.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!